# Magento 2: Override admin layout didn't work

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

I would like to override this quotation_quote_view.xml file layout (from a custom module) and add a block
below this block reminder_date

```
<block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\ReminderDate" template="quote/view/reminderdate.phtml" name="reminder_date"/>
```

quotation_quote_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!--
~ Copyright (c) 2019. Cart2Quote B.V. All rights reserved.
~ See COPYING.txt for license details.
-->

<!--
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Cart2Quote_Quotation::js/bootstrap/quote-view-index.js"/>
    <css src="Cart2Quote_Quotation::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<update handle="quotation_quote_view_item_price"/>
<update handle="quotation_quote_view_items"/>
<update handle="quotation_quote_view_load_block_totals"/>
<body>
    <!-- Move the quote items after search see handle: quotation_quote_view_items -->
    <move element="items" destination="data" after="search"/>
    <!-- Move the quote items after search see handle: quotation_quote_view_items -->
    <move element="totals" destination="data" after="reminder_date"/>
    <referenceContainer name="admin.scope.col.wrap" htmlClass="admin__old"/>
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setTitleId">
            <argument translate="true" name="id" xsi:type="string">order-header</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="js">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Cart2Quote_Quotation::quote/view/js.phtml" name="view"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View" name="quotation_quote_view"/>
        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\CustomProduct" template="Cart2Quote_Quotation::quote/create/customProductModal.phtml" name="custom_product_modal"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Tabs" name="quotation_quote_tabs">
            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Tab\Info" name="quote_tab_info" template="quote/view/tab/info.phtml">
                <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Messages" name="message"/>
                <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Data" template="quote/view/data.phtml" name="data">
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\Sections" name="quote_sections" template="Cart2Quote_Quotation::quote/view/actions/sections.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Shipping\Method" template="quote/view/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Shipping\Method\Form" template="quote/view/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="quote.view.shipping.method.form" as="form">
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Shipping\Method\Form\Quotation" template="quote/view/shipping/method/form/quotation.phtml" name="quote.view.shipping.method.form.quotation"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Search" template="quote/view/abstract.phtml" name="search">
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Search\Grid" name="search_grid" as="grid"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Data" template="quote/view/subtotalProposal.phtml" name="proposal"/>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_details" template="quote/view/details.phtml">
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Details\Account\Details" name="quote_details_account_details" template="quote/view/details/account/details.phtml">
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Details\Account\Details" name="quote_details_account_fields_customer_name" template="quote/view/details/account/fields/customerName.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Details\Account\Details" name="quote_details_account_fields_email" template="quote/view/details/account/fields/email.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Details\Account\Details" name="quote_details_account_fields_customer_group" template="quote/view/details/account/fields/customerGroup.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Details\Account\Details" name="quote_details_account_fields_customer_account_data" template="quote/view/details/account/fields/customerAccountData.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_details_quote_details" template="quote/view/details/quote/details.phtml">
                            <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\SelectRate" name="quote_details_quote_select_rate" template="quote/view/details/quote/selectRate.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_details_order_details" template="quote/view/details/order/details.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Comment" name="quote_details_quote_comment" template="quote/view/details/quote/comment.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_address" template="quote/view/address.phtml">
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_address_billing" template="quote/view/address/billing.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_address_shipping" template="quote/view/address/shipping.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\QuoteDate" template="quote/view/quotedate.phtml" name="quote_date"/>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\QuoteStatus" template="quote/view/quotestatus.phtml" name="quote_status"/>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\ExpiryDate" template="quote/view/expirydate.phtml" name="expiry_date"/>
                    <block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\ReminderDate" template="quote/view/reminderdate.phtml" name="reminder_date"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="quote_item_extra_info"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">quote_info</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">quote_tab_info</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Configure" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/composite/configure.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="quotation_page_head_components" template="Cart2Quote_Quotation::page/js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

So I created a module and a layout file under Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/quotation_quote_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="data">

        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\DailyCron" after="reminder_date" name="quote_daily_cron" template="quote/daily_cron.phtml"/>

    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

In view/adminhtml/templates/quote/daily_cron.phtml

```
<?php
$quote = $block->getQuote();

?>
<div class="admin__field field-comment ">
<th>
    <label for="quote-reminder-date" class="admin__field-label">
        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Daily reminder')) ?></span>
    </label>
</th>
<td>
    <div class="admin__field-control">


    </div>
</td>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work, so how to override a layout and add a block after a given block?

Answer (score 1):

Inside **module.xml** file, you have to declare dependency of core module,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Change the module **Magento_Sales** whatever you want to override this layout..

You have to first check if any log error are generated for this layout.

**You have to just clear cache and remove var folder.**

Comment: I'm trying to override a custom module Cart2Quote i've already put this code in module.xml <module name="Wetag_DailyCron" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Cart2Quote_Quotation"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>

Comment: You have to just clear cache and remove var folder.

Comment: Please check your layout file path like this:
       
**app/code/Wetag/DailyCron/view/adminhtml/layout/quotation_quote_view.xml**

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**:
Inside quotation_quote_view.xml file, you have to override the the details block.

```
<block class="Cart2Quote\Quotation\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\View\Info" name="quote_details_quote_details" template="Vendor_Cart2QuoteQuotation::quote/view/details/quote/details.phtml">
```

**Step 2**:
Inside the details.phtml line 56, add the html block.

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('quote_daily_cron') ?>
```

**Step 3**: Clear cache